# XML Task- Failed to lock variable error

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

[image][XML Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Failed to lock variable "\canada01.ifdsnet.int\ifds\Deptshare3\Automated_Data_Feeds\SVN_Logs\Final.xml" for read/write access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".
".

I keep getting this error, eventhough my destination is a file connection and not a variable, can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

change the sourcetype to file connection not to variable, if you want to dynamic file change expression connection in file. read this guide:

[Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2007/12/15/xml-source-making-things-easier-with-xslt/)

Ask me the next question you need ;).

Comment: but its complaining on the destination and not the source, i am using a variable for the source because there are many xml files so i have used a foreach loop to go through each xml file and execute the xml task for each xml file!! hope this make sense to you, if not let me know i will try to breif it more

Comment: i think we cant use a variable in xml task!. I just tested this, i created a variable with the path to the xml file and used that as the source by selecting sourcetype=variable and creating an expression for source whcih would just be the variable name. It failed complaining the variable cannot be found